# bootstrap building gcc - stage 2 and 3 comparison fail

Tags: gcc, build, checksum, bootstrapping

rm -f stage_current
make[3]: Leaving directory `/d/Projects/compiler/gcc-build'
Comparing stages 2 and 3
warning: gcc/cc1-checksum.o differs
warning: gcc/cc1plus-checksum.o differs
Bootstrap comparison failure!
libcpp/charset.o differs
make[2]: *** [compare] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`/d/Projects/compiler/gcc-build'
make[1]: *** [stage3-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Projects/compiler/gcc-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2

basically my bootstrap building of gcc (host on i686-pc-mingw32 and target i686-pc-mingw32) fails as the binary comparison fails...

anybody have any ideas as to why this is??

i've been making parallel makes with the option "-j" (i really have to get this build ready as soon as i can), but i don't think it could've caused the differences...

UPDATE:
ok, in case this is just a fundamental error, such as no binary comparison for the bootstrap can be effectively done in the given environment -- mingw (probably have to be seriously patched in the future), how do i skip this checking process??

Comment: Please specify exact GCC version, that you are trying to build. There are several known bootstrap bugs.

Comment: @Konstantin: build system is libtool 2.4, binutils 2.24, gcc 4.9.1 c, c++ (non-bootstrapped) -- all compiled. recompiled mingwrt and w32api as well. gcc being bootstrapped is also gcc 4.9.1.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't set up --build= or --target= because the architecture is x86_64 not i686, so it fails me when I was compiling my gcc-4.9.1 on a Mac Mini with option --build=i686-***
You can try --disable-checking but not so sure.

Comment: MinGW is buggy. Please don't compile gcc on that... --target is only need for cross build ( if you will change root later something... )

Answer (score -1):

you can try these commands:

```
$ make distclean
$ ./configure
```

and them try to make again